# Calculate the number of distinct possible values of the array after the repeated process of absolute difference between any 2 elements

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hashset

This was a question asked in a mock test. So, I could not find any online evaluator for this.

Basically, you are provided with an array of elements. You can take any 2 elements and add their absolute difference back to the array.

The solution should be the number of distinct values in the array after infinite number of above given step.

**Example 1-**

Input [2,3,4,5]

Output - 5

**Explanation:** Since 3-2=1, this can be added to the set. So the total number of distinct values will be 5.

**Example 2-**

Input [1,100]

Output - 100

**Explanation -**  100-1 = 99 -> add this back to the set

Then, 99-1 = 98 -> add this back to the set.

After repeating the process, all the numbers from 1 to 100 will be present in the set.

I used a hash set to store the distinct elements to store the initial array elements and used 2 for loops to subtract the store the distinct result to the same array-
But only after submitting my code, i realized, the distinct result should be again used for further subtraction.

Hence my answer was wrong.

Can anyone help me solve this ? Thanks in advance.

Edit : correcting the solution of first example to 5 instead of 6.

Comment: There are only 5 elements between 1 to 5, why the answer is 6?

Comment: @Yonlif , you are right. My mistake. Will edit it.

Comment: The solution is `maximum(array) / gcd(array)`.

Comment: @ גלעד ברקן. You are right. Thanks. Understood it when I thought it through.

Comment: Can someone explain why is the answer `maximum(array) / gcd(array)`?

Answer (score 0):

Adding explanation for `maximum(array)/gcd(array)` as pointed out in the comments.

- `gcd(array)` - the greatest common divisor for all the numbers in the array is calculated i.e. the largest number that divides all the values in the array. It is known that division is nothing but repeated subtractions. So, no matter how many times we were to find absolute difference of the numbers in the array, GCD of the numbers is the maximum we can reduce the difference to. For an instance, let's say the array is `[2, 10]`, the array can only be become `[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]`. Other numbers in this range will never get added, that is, an absolute difference of `1` never occurs.
- `maximum(array)` - we are finding difference here, so at any point, the difference cannot exceed the maximum value.

Therefore, `maximum(array)/gcd(array)` formula gives the right output for the question.

Hope this helps!